Opening a file from another drive does not work
I am using the following code to open a text file
CStdioFile f;

CString sPath = "E:\\Folder\\test.txt"  
                                      
//Open the text file
if (f.Open(sPath, CFile::modeRead))
{
     int i = 0;
}

This works.
However the text file I need to read is located in the C:\ drive. If I set sPath to "C:\\Folder\\test.txt" the program no longer opens the file. Note that the program itself is located in the E:\\ drive.
I verified that the user running the program has read access to C:\\Folder\\test.txt. I would expect to be able to open this file given that the user has read permissions, but I am unable to do so.
Edit: I am escaping the backslashes above, for some reason Stackoverflow is getting rid of the second backslash in the post.

You should properly escape those those backslashes in the path.

Side note : why not use C++'s standard file streams and strings? E.g. std::ifstream and std::string? (I always try to solve as much as I can in standard C++ and interact with framework/OS specific stuff at the edges of my code). Eg. build unit testable C++ static libraries first.

Do you have compiler warnings disabled? In Visual C++ 2022 I get a warning about the invalid escape sequence \F: warning C4129: 'F': unrecognized character escape sequence

prefer raw string literals R"(E:\Folder\test.txt)" that don't need any escape. If the path is correct then check your file permissions

Check error value returned or GetLastError()

There's no reason that a file would not open just because it's on a different drive to your program. Whatever the reason is for the failure it is not that. I have no idea what it is however.

Sounds like a good time to bust out procmon and look at the actual system call result.

Also note that forward slashes works just as well on Windows, without having to be escaped in string literals.

@BoP not in all cases, some APIs won't accept slashes. But since this is C++, it's much better to use std::filesystem for std calls and let it handle all the FS differences
